# Chromefy (Chrome OS) on RPi3B+?

Tags: pi-3b+, chrome-os

Has anyone tried using Chromefy (a way to get official Chrome OS on any device) or similar Chromium OS releases on the RPi3B+? If so, which one works best?

Comment: please define `works best`

Comment: Smoothest running, most features (especially Google Play), least bugs